# How to get all items of checklistbox to list c#?

Tags: c#, list, get, checkedlistbox

I tried below code but does not work.

```
  checkedListBox1.Items.OfType<String>().ToList();
```

it is working for selected items, but does not work for this. Is there any other way by not using any loop?

Comment: What does the rest of your code look like?

Comment: Do you mean that your code is returning only selected items but not returning items which are not selected?

Comment: checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<String>().ToList(); it is working for that, but i wantto select all items

Comment: The code in the question, which should work fine, will get all items and the code with `CheckedItems` will get only the items that have been selected. Use one or the other depending on what you want. If the code isn't working, what's the error message you're getting?

Comment: How do you add the strings to the checked list box?

Comment: there is no error, list is empty but checkedlistbox is not empty. i am adding items by using this code checkedListBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);

Answer (score 2):

Items should work for all items, SelectedItems just for those that are selected

```
var allItems = checkedListBox1.Items.OfType<String>().ToList();
```

Use SelectedItems for items currently selected (as in, which are currently highlighted):

```
var selectedItems = checkedListBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<String>().ToList();
```

To get items currently checked:

```
var checkedItems = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.OfType<String>().ToList();
```

Comment: var allItems = checkedListBox1.Items.OfType<String>().ToList(); allitems is null but checkedlistbox have items.

Comment: You might be attempting to retrieve items before the checked list box contains them. Try setting a breakpoint in a few places in your code and seeing how the checked list box is populated/processed.